# erc20 balanceOf function in Foundry test code

Tags: foundry

I'm testing using foundry. Isn't it correct syntax for balanceOf ? I don'k know why but it keeps revert.

```js
assertEq(IERC20(address(ico)).balanceOf(address(attacker)), 10 * ONE_TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following code

```
console.log(IERC20(address(ico)).balanceOf(address(attacker)));
assertEq(IERC20(address(ico)).balanceOf(address(attacker)), 10 * ONE_TOKEN);
```

This will print out the current balance of the attacker address in the console, which can help you determine if the issue is with the balanceOf function call or the assertion itself.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that tripped me up is that not all forge commands use the `ETH_RPC_URL` environment variable. Make sure the `--rpc-url` argument is set when you run your command, otherwise onchain calls will revert.

E.g. [forge create](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge/forge-create#rpc-options) and [cast send](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/cast/cast-send#rpc-options) use the environment variable, while [forge test](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge/forge-test#evm-options) and [forge script](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge/forge-script#evm-options) do not.